# Проблема jQuery.each

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class='item-box'>
   <li class='item' id='1'>Элемент 1</li>
   <li class='item' id='2'>Элемент 2</li>
   <li class='item' id='3'>Элемент 3</li>
</ul>

var items = '';

$('.item-box li').each(function(index){
   items = 'Элемент id='+$(this).text();
});

alert(items);
```

выводится только один элемент, как сделать чтобы выводились все элементы списка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например, так

```
var items = [];

$('.item-box li').each(function(index){
    items.push('Элемент id='+index);
});

alert(items.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Стоит лишь дописать плюсик:

```
$('.item-box li').each(function(index){
   items += $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: @lampa, [для такой операции][1] и цикла не нужно ;)

    $('#output').text($('.item-box li').text());

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/PzLQ4/

Comment: @Deonis и то верно!)

Comment: в исходной задаче текст не тот, что `.text()`